# query AD to find computers in use by users in a OU

Tags: sccm

I want to deploy an Outlook VSTO via SCCM to computers from enduser in an certain ou. Is there a script to export these computer hostnames|username|OU?

thanks in advance.

Comment: So example, I want to install app via SCCM to all laptops in use by HR personel.

Comment: you should try something first, come here when you hit a wall. Not expecting people to solve the entire problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/sccm-2012-creating-device-collections.html) on how to create AD Query based collections.

System OU Name is the attribute you want to query on.